# How to upload a zip file to s3 using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I zip a folder having multiple subdirectories. When I upload it to s3 using boto
 By reading like this,

```
zipdata = open(os.path.join(os.curdir, zip_file), 'rb').read()
```

Then all files from all subdirectries copied to root directory. That is no subdirectory exists at s3.

How to upload a zip file of a folder to s3?

Comment: You can fake directories by putting slashes in the file-name.

Comment: Is the end goal to put the zip file in the bucket, or to put each file inside the zip in the bucket? As the previous two comments suggest, there are no 'directories' in s3 buckets, but by using slashes you can emulate directories...

Answer (score 0):

After running the command you show above, `zip_data` will contain the bytes contained in the zip file.  If you then write that data to S3, you will get a single object (key) in S3 that contains that data.  Is that what you want?

It sounds like you want the zip file to be expanded and all of the individual files and directories inside it to be stored in S3 as individual objects.  If that is the case, you need to expand the zip file locally and then walk through the hierarchy and store each individual file in S3.  You could use the `s3put` command line tool in boto to do this for you.

There is no way to get S3 itself to unpack the contents of a zip file for you automatically.